# "Nibble at it" or "nibble on it"?

Tags: prepositions

Example sentence:

> I cut another bit of meat and nibble at/on it.

What's the correct preposition? I aske because Google shows that both are used.

Comment: It would help if you provided more details about what you searched for and what you found out when you checked Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really necessary to use either preposition. This sentence is fine without a preposition:

> I cut another bit of meat and nibble it.

If I wanted to focus on the comsumption of something, I would use **on**, in the same way as one can dine **on** something.

If I wanted to focus on the effect it has on the thing that is being nibbled- the removal of small pieces from the edge or surface of it- I would use **at**, in the same way as a cat might scratch **at** a door.

Comment: Or, one could go in other direction, and use [_nibble away at_](http://onelook.com/?w=nibble+away+at&ls=a).

Comment: @J.R. again, that's about the effect it's having on the thing that's being nibbled: "Beware of hidden costs that can nibble away at your budget.".

Answer (score 1):

If you eat something slowly or with small bites, you can use the verb nibble without a preposition or with the preposition at/on, without any difference in meaning: So you can say:

I cut another bit of meat and nibbled it.

I cut another bit of meat and nibbled at/on it.

Besides, you can also use nibble, nibble at, or nibble on, when you gently bite a part of someone's body. For example:

He nibbled/nibbled at/nibbled on her neck affectionately.

When you show a slight interest in an idea or offer, you can use "nibble at" as follows:

I nibbled at the idea.

The nibble with the preposition "at" is also used to convey the sense that something affects somethiny or causes something to disappear gradually as follIows:

The police have been nibbling at crime in the city for 2 years.

Inflation is nibbling at our purchasing power.

Comment: Where is the evidence that "at" is more common than "on"? And does that even make a difference in the O.P.'s context?

Comment: [alternate ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nibble+at+a%2Cnibble+on+a&year_start=1975&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3); [alternate ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nibbling+at+a%2Cnibbling+on+a&year_start=1975&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

Although both the idioms "to nibble at something" and "to nibble on something" have the meaning of eating by small bites, in the former that something is [always some kind of food](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nibble+at), whereas in the latter it may also be something that you bite but [not break its surface](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nibble+on).

Examples:

> The rabbit nibbled on/at a carrot.
>
> Fish were nibbling at the bait
>
> He nibbled nervously on his fingernail.

So regarding your sentence, there's no difference; although I'd prefer "nibble at".

Comment: It is possible to nibble things besides food, though (for example, _nibbling at a [problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nibbling+at+the+problem%22)_ is idiomatic speech). Also, see [Collins, definition 4](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nibble).

Comment: @Rompe, It's misguiding to  say that "at" is always used for some kind of food. See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nibbled+on+her+ear.%2Cnibbled+at+her+ear%2C+nibbled+her+ear&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Khan - That’s a common pitfall when we rely on (and put too much stock in) a [single dictionary definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nibble+at).